# Access parent-child forms not filtering correctly

Tags: vba, filtering, parent-child

I have a database that has a main form which links to tblClientMaster.  The subform then is linked to the parent by ClientName.  You can search on the parent window to filter by client name and the records on the subform filter accordingly.  On the child window, you can then search by participant name.  The source for the child window is tblCalculations.  The problem I am having is that the child window will not perform the search.  Nothing is being filtered.

You click the search button (search by name).  The search button runs this code:

```
    Private Sub NameSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_NameSearch_Click
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter FilterName:="qryCalcNameSearch"
Exit_NameSearch_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_NameSearch_Click:
    Resume Exit_NameSearch_Click
End Sub
```

The query has the following SQL code:

```
SELECT tblCalculations.ParticipantLastName, tblClientMaster.ClientName
FROM tblCalculations LEFT JOIN tblClientMaster ON tblCalculations.ClientName=tblClientMaster.ClientName
WHERE (((tblCalculations.ParticipantLastName) Like "*" & [Enter Participant Name Here] & "*") And ((tblClientMaster.ClientName)=Forms!frmMain!ClientNameMain));
```

(ClientNameMain is the text field on the parent form that contains the name of the currently selected client)

What happens when I click this button, it first gives me an input box that says "tblCalculations.ParticipantLastName" which I do not want to appear, but I enter it.  It then prompts me with "Enter Participant Name Here" which is what I wanted it to do.  I don't know why it is giving me the first input box at all.  When I enter the name into both boxes, nothing happens and no filtering occurs.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone?  I haven't been able to get this to work at all...

Comment: Also, the subform is linked to the master form by ClientName.  The subform field linker has Master fields: ClientName and Child Fields: ClientName.  Everything I've seen in these forums indicate that these two need to be linked.  They are, but I still can't seem to get it to work.